# windows powershell add text to the beginning of each object in a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
samaccountname,enabled
user1,false
user2,false
```

I want to take each entry in the samaccaountname column and add this exact text:

C:\Users\

then I need to create a new csv file that only contains a single column with the new data like this:

```
header
C:\Users\User1
C:\Users\User2
C:\Users\User3
```

what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've been playing with using this:

Import-Csv -Delim ';' disabled.csv | Foreach {$_.samaccountname = "prepend\$($_.samaccountname)";$_} |
     Export-Csv dispaths.csv -Delim ';' -NoTypeInformation

but its telling me it can't find the property im specifying.  I thought for sure I was barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: Read in file to a powershell object, loop through each instance in the CSV and change the property value and then rewrite it back to the file.

Comment: You should not put code into comments; edit your question to include the new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to skin this cat is to use the custom property creation via Select-Object:

```
import-csv $yourcsv | Select-Object *,@{Name="fullpath";Expression={"C:\users\$($_.path)"}} | export-csv -notypeinformation $newcsv
```

this time, tested and does work.

Edit:  and if you don't want the original property, just change Select object to select the properties you do want with the custom property included.

Comment: thanks for this.  however, i keep getting "The property 'samaccountname' cannot be found on this object."  when I run it.  I am certain cell A1 contains exactly this text: samaccountname.  what am I missing here?

Comment: this was supposed to be a sample to get you in the right direction.  assign 'gc $sourcefile' to a variable, look at the property names it imports and then replace 'samaccountname' with whatever property it is tha tyou want to append "C:\users" to

Comment: @soltkr `gc` is `Get-Content` which won't have that property, using `Import-CSV` would get rid of that error.

Comment: @thepip3r  sorry, I should have been more clear.  I didnt just copy and past your example into the powershell.  I altered it to fit my csv filename and the column heading I want to append is samaccountname

Comment: thanks for the correction  benh -- oversight on my part.

Comment: @benh making that change quited the errors and created the export .csv file.  however it was empty.  i changed the export-csv at the end of the code to out-file and tried again but I got the same thing an empty csv file...

Comment: @soltkr This is because nothing is being returned in the `ForEach-Object` loop. Here is thepip3r's code with the corrections as a one-liner `(Import-CSV $sourcefile | % {$_.samaccountname = "C:\users\$($_.samaccountname)"; $_}) | Export-CSV $newfile` Note that this will still export a file with two columns. You could either use `Remove-Member` if you didn't want to just create a new object.

Comment: @benh thanks team!  that worked perfectly AND I learned something...so there's that.

Answer (score 0):

Import the csv, loop through the entries of that csv, for each of them create an object with the property name you want. Then export

```
$DataToExport = Import-CSV $sourcefile | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "Header" = "C:\Users\$($_.samaccountname)"
    }
} 
$DataToExport | Export-CSV $newfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: There was an erroneous trailing `"` at the pscustomobject.